# Javascript regexp does not match date correctly

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I'm trying to filter out date results, but I think I may have the regular expression wrong.

```
if ((strSearchInx == 6) || (strSearchInx == 7)) {
       var regDate = new RegExp("/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/");
       strSearchField = strSearchField.trim();
       //alert(strSearchField);
       if (regDate.test(strSearchField) == false) {
          alert("Date does not match mm/dd/yyyy format. Please re-enter");
          document.getElementById('searchfield').focus();
          return false;
       }

     }
```

I've tested it against 8/3/2016 and it doesn't seem to let any response through:  Is /^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$/ the correct regular expression?

Thanks.

Comment: seems to work https://regex101.com/r/uN2sH3/1 . are you sure the input is correct?

Comment: Use regex literal syntax `/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/` OR `new RegExp("^\\d{1,2}\/\\d{1,2}\/\\d{4}$")`

Comment: Are you testing this regex to the exact string "8/3/2016" , or to a string containing that date?

Comment: Should do what you expect so perhaps strSearchInx is not 6/7 chars long

Comment: Don't forget to change your error message, since m/d/yyyy, mm/d/yyyy and m/dd/yyyy seem to be allowed as well

Comment: @Tushar : `new RegExp("^\\d{1,2}\/\\d{1,2}\/\\d{4}$")` without / at start and end

Comment: Tried putting it in literally:  `var regDate = new RegExp("/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/");
       strSearchField = strSearchField.trim();
       //alert(strSearchField);
       if (regDate.test("8/3/2016") == false) {
          alert("Date does not match mm/dd/yyyy format. Please re-enter");
          document.getElementById('searchfield').focus();
          return false;
       }`  Still does not let it go through.

Comment: @JohnMeyer Use the literal format. When using the `RegExp` constructor the backslashes need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using Regexp object correctly.
You should do :

```
var regDate = new RegExp("^\\d{1,2}\/\\d{1,2}\/\\d{4}$");
```

See how `\d` is escaped, and you should not start and end your regexp with `/`, it's used to start and end literal regexp, not regexp wrapped in an object.

Comment: Cool ! You're welcome.